# Cosine Similarity of the word embeddings after UMAP dimensionality reduction

Tags: python, clustering, word-embeddings, cosine-similarity

I want to calculate similarities of the word embeddings. As a basis I took SpaCy german corpus: `nlp = spacy.load("de_core_news_lg")`.

1. I have approximately 200 thousands words with 300 embedding dimensions. I needed to cluster all my words into clusters(other task) and after some experiments i figured out, that with normalized embedding clusterization works better.
2. For normalization I have used 2-nd norm: `self.data.apply(lambda x: x['embedding']/np.linalg.norm(x['embedding'],ord = 2), axis=1)`, where `x['embedding']` is an 300-dim numpy array.
3. My experiments showed, that clusterization works best with 50 dimension. That's why i have used `UMAP` clusterization.
4. For clustering I have used `hdbscan` algorithm.
5. After that I want to compute cosine_similarity between elements. But my results are weird. For example cosine_similarity between `'Python' and 'Java' is 0.0`. But for totally different(by meaning) words similarity is close to 1(for example: 'Football' and 'Phone').

Is there any reason for such behaviour of cosine_similarity measurement? Euclidean distance works as expected(Between Python and Java close to 0 and Football and Phone is large).

If I don't use UMAP, cosine_similarity words as expected.

Cosine Similarity implementation:

```
cos_sim = round(dot(emb1, emb2)/(norm(emb1)*norm(emb2)),3)
```

Euclidean Distance implementation:

```
eucl_dist = round(np.linalg.norm(emb1 - emb2),3)
```